# Request file through email

Tags: php, email

I want public users to have the possibilty to "order" a file (that is already on the webpage/server) through a form. After the form has been submitted successfully, an email should be sent to the entered user email with the file that has been ordered. Payment is not necessary! It's only about the sending process!

I'm searching a way to do it with an addon, but can't find one. Postmaster, Firemail, Forms, Freeform - all those are great tools for building forms, or sending mails - but no possibility to easy handling file attachements? Is there any other?

Might it be a solution to use PHP-Code within the "FormSubmitSuccessful"-Template and do it "on the fly" with phpmailer, for instance? Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any add-ons that will attach the file to send attached to the email itself, having said that the easiest solution would be to use FreeForm or similar add-ons to collect the users information.

Then in your FreeForm user email template you would add a link to the file on your server or a download page that would allow the user to download the attached file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with freeform: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/